# using selenium-rc can i load a page, click a bookmarklet, and fill up the in-page loaded form?

Tags: selenium, bookmarklet

Is there anyway by which I can automate the following steps
in Selenium-rc

1. open a page
2. click on bookmarklet in browser toolbar
3. fill up data in the form loaded into the page by said bookmarklet.

If the bookmarklet is not accessible as it is part of the browser/bookmark toolbar,
is there a way in which I can inject the javascript into the page and have it execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are 99% there! You're right, you can't actually click the bookmarklet, but you can inject the same JavaScript in to the page. Simply use the getEval() command to evaluate the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, the RobotFramework-SeleniumLibrary equivalent is "Execute Javascript"